Alignment of bolt holes after front collision
I had a front collision in which there was a slight damage to the chassis. I had the chassis repaired by a chassis expert (they pulled it back and made some measurements).
However, there is still a problem. As you can see in the following pictures, these two bolt holes don't line up properly. These bolts connect radiator fan tray to the fender and upper edge of the chassis. I also noticed that the upper radiator hose is now touching the intake box which wasn't the case before the accident.
I talked about the issue with the chassis expert but he said he had done his job perfectly and that the issue has nothing to do with the chassis!
What I don't understand is that how could it be possible that the bolt holes still don't line up even after straightening the chassis to its original shape?!
2003 Peugeot 406



Why? Because the chassis (frame) is only part of the equation. There are other parts which are between the frame and the body pieces (ie: fenders, hood, bumper) which provide support for the body pieces.  These support pieces are out of alignment, which is causing the bolt holes not to line up.
The great thing for you is, there's two sides to your car. Both sides usually have identical mounting systems as well as hole/fastener spacing ... it's just on the opposite side of the vehicle.
My suggestion to you is, take the fender off of the side you're working on and check the support pieces to see if there is any damage done to them. If there is, straighten/rebend those back to right. Check the distance from a bolt hole you're trying to make right back to a bolt hole in an area which was unaffected by the accident (closer to the windshield), then measure the same distances between the corresponding holes on the opposite side of the vehicle to see how far the side you're working on is out. This will give you an idea of how far you need to move the holes to make things right. You should be able to do this for any spacing you're trying to figure out.
There are publications which cover the spacing I'm talking about, but they are pay for service kinds of things. Most auto manufacturers have this information already, but it does come at a cost.
EDIT: I happened to look closer at one of the photos (bottom one).

Look at the area with the red circle. This is the "good" side. You can see the area arcs nicely from support up to the fender. Now look at the blue circled area. There is a crease at the corner. This is damage in the support structure which needs to be fixed/replaced before you should be trying to line up the fender. If you asked for the chassis/frame to be fixed, this would not be part of what was to be fixed. I'm sure there are other areas which are going to need help, too.

Dear Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, Thanks for your information and analysis. The photo you are referring to was taken before chassis repair. That blue circled area has now been repaired and straightened and looks like the red (unaffected) area. This was done by the chassis repair shop. The alignment issue still exists after repairing the damaged corner. I think I should try other parts.

@LFYMP7.3 - No worries ... I'm sure the misalignment is being cause by something similar. Hopefully this answer gives you the clues you need to figure out where the misalignment is occuring. Also, don't think straight forward and back when checking distances, also check from crosswise across the engine. Also, be as precise as possible when making your measurements. It'll help in the end and hopefully help you to find the parts which need adjusting to get things right.
